# Как сделать OutputStream больше одного

Tags: java, xml, input

Привет всем.Задача стоит такая, считать XML(размером 9МБ) через InputStream и вывести новые три файла, по 3 мб в новую папку

```
    import java.io.*;

public class convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            // считать файл
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("D://input.xml");

            // записать байты в новый файл
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://XML/new.xml"));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            System.out.println("Записано!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

У меня получилось только создать такой же файл. Как сделать 3 файла с заданным размером?спасибо

Comment: вы хотите просто так взять и порезать xml на три равные по размеру в байтах части?

Comment: Во-первых, XML это как правило целостная структура, и разбивать один xml файл на 3 как-то не логично (впрочем, я не знаю вашей задачи). Во-вторых, елси уж нужно разбить файл на три равные части, то просто узнаете его размер, делите на три, пишете первую треть в один OutputStream, затем закрываете его, открываете следующий и т.д.. Не вижу проблемы.

Comment: у меня структура абсолютно одинаковая, так что на это не обращайте внимания) А по поводу вашего совета, мне нужно создать 3 Output метода или как? а где указать размер?

Comment: Каждый из этих трёх выходных файлов должен быть правильным XML?

Comment: да! Структура не важна, мне просто их надо поделить!

Comment: Просто поделить файл на равные части не сложно. но сохранить корректность сложнее, нужно знать структуру xml входного файла